# How to show that pairs of functions are of the same order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

If we have these pairs of functions, how can we show that they are of the same
order?

a) $3x + 7,\quad x$

b) $2x^2 + x − 7,\quad x^2$

c) $\lfloor x + 1/2\rfloor ,\quad x$

d) $\log(x^2 + 1),\quad \log_2 x$

e) $\log_{10} x,\quad \log_2 x$

Thanks guys!

Comment: Define "order of function" if you don't mind...

Comment: Not entirely sure what they mean by it either!

Comment: If you can prove that the limit of the ratio is a non-zero constant, that will do it.

Comment: Andre and Peter seem to be sure what "order of function" means, but neither you nor I are...I would expect, though, that the one asking the question will at least know what the question is.

Answer (score 3):

You want to show that $\dfrac f g \to K$ as $x\to\infty$, where $K\neq 0$ is some constant. For polynomials, this is almost immediate. For the logarithms, you can use L'Hôpital.

Comment: That's pretty much the answer.

Comment: It's hard to do this with Floors, though

Comment: Floors? @JennaMagic

Comment: Yes, C should be a floor of that first function! =(

Comment: I edited. @JennaMagic

Comment: This is a sufficient condition, but it’s not necessary. You want to show that there are positive $c_1\le c_2$ such that $c_1\le\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\le c_2$ for all sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Well, that is the definition I learned. Maybe there are other definitions, and as you note, not equivalent ones.

Comment: We can only hope that the OP’s instructor clarifies matters!

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation of the claim that $f$ and $g$ are of the same order is that $f=\Theta(g)$ as $x\to\infty$. By definition this means that there are $x_0,c_1,c_2>0$ such that

$$c_1g(x)\le f(x)\le c_2g(x)\quad\text{for all }x\ge x_0\;.$$

Of course this is equivalent to

$$c_1\le\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\le c_2\quad\text{for all }x\ge x_0\;.$$

This is weaker than saying that $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ approaches a positive limit as $x\to\infty$, as may be seen by considering the functions $f(x)=100+\sin x$ and $g(x)=100$. However, the pairs in the question all meet the stronger requirement, though it may take a moment to see this in for (c):

$$x\le\left\lfloor x+\frac12\right\rfloor\le x+1\;,$$

so

$$1\le\frac{\left\lfloor x+\frac12\right\rfloor}x\le1+\frac1x\;,$$

and $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left\lfloor x+\frac12\right\rfloor}x=1\;.$$

For the pairs involving logarithms, remember that $\log_ax=\dfrac{\log_bx}{\log_ba}$.